# AngularJS - Routing and templating of a SPA

Tags: angularjs, routes, templating

I'm a beginner with angularJS and I keep wasting my time on little questions because I don't understand how to organize an internal routing service with protected files and routes. I would be really thankfull to anyone who could give me some explanations or links to give me the theory that i'm lacking. :]

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like ui-router?
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Thanks you that seems like a good tool :) It looks cleaner  than ng-routes. I've got another question : how could i secure some routes and files ? I'm actually using a restfull nodeJs API with requests secured with JSON web-tokens. Is the client part using this service or use its own ?